# Meaning of 'wear'

Tags: word-usage

The below sentence is from the [Oxford online dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deploy):

> ‘Professor Furia wears his learning lightly, but he deploys it to great effect.’

I would like to know what 'wear' means in that sentence. Does it mean to 
tolerate'?

Answer (score 4):

If you wear something lightly, then you don't show it off. For example,

> 1. You don't become president without clawing your way into the Oval Office, but voters prefer pols like JFK, Ronald Reagan and Barack
>      Obama who **wear their ambition lightly**. ([source](https://www.mysanantonio.com/news/article/Candidates-blame-ambition-on-wives-2438940.php)) (they don't
>      draw attention to their ambition)
> 2. I don’t always **wear my knowledge lightly**. I like learning, and I like passing on that knowledge. ([source](http://frydman.co.uk/lord-peter-wimsey-wearing-your-knowledge-lightly/)) (I don't always keep
>      quiet about what I know, I like to share it)

So, "Professor Furia **wears his learning lightly**" means he doesn't flaunt it, he doesn't look like [a know-it-all](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know-it-all). Rather, "he deploys it to great effect", which means he takes advantage of his strength.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds metaphorical to me. I read it as if it's treating 'learning'  like it were 'clothes'. Something you figuratively wear.

Like heart in the idiomatic phrase [**to wear your heart on your sleeve**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wear-your-heart-on-your-sleeve).